# How to retrive textbox text from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which contains textboxes and dropdowns.In gvScheduleBattingScore_RowDataBound Event I am binding dropdowns without any problem. The button control is outside to the gridview. I actually want to submit all the textbox values and dropdown selected values to the database on **buttonclickevent** But I don't know where I am going wrong.
The Problem is Textboxes do not contain any text and am getting Exception

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Please help me out...

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvScheduleBattingScore" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false"
                 GridLines="None" CellPadding="1" CssClass="GridViewStyle" ShowFooter="false" width="100%"
                 OnRowDataBound="gvScheduleBattingScore_RowDataBound">                
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_PlayerId" HeaderText="Player Id" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" Visible="false"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerName" HeaderText="Player Name" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Width="30%"/>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Playing Order" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlayingOrder" runat="server" CssClass="TinyTexBox"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bold By">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoldBy" runat="server">                       </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
</br>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="SmallButton" 
                                 ValidationGroup="Add" onclick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
```

On ButtonClick Event:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection dBConnection = null;
            try
            {
                int playerId;
                short plyerOrder;
                string BatsmanStatus;
                int boldBy;

                dBConnection = new SqlConnection();
                dBConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CriConn"].ConnectionString;

                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertScores", dBConnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (GridViewRow GVRow in gvScheduleBattingScore.Rows)
                {
                    string textPlayerId = GVRow.Cells[0].Text;
                    TextBox textPlyerOrder = (TextBox)GVRow.Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlayingOrder"); 
                    TextBox textBatsmanStatus = GVRow.Cells[2].FindControl("txtStatus") as TextBox;
                    DropDownList DropDownBoldBy = (DropDownList)GVRow.Cells[18].FindControl("ddlBoldBy");

playerId = Convert.ToInt32(textPlayerId );
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textPlyerOrder.Text))
                        plyerOrder = Convert.ToInt16(textPlyerOrder.Text);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBatsmanStatus.Text))
                        BatsmanStatus = textBatsmanStatus.Text;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownBoldBy.SelectedValue) && DropDownLbwBy.SelectedValue != "Select")
                        boldBy = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownBoldBy.SelectedValue);

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlayerId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = playerId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlayerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = playerId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@plyerOrder", SqlDbType.Int).Value = plyerOrder;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BatsmanStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = BatsmanStatus;

                    dBConnection.Open();
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dBConnection.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Close data reader object and database connection
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cmd = null;
                    if (dBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        dBConnection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Can u tell me where you are getting the exact error..

Comment: On ButtonAdd_Click Event When I am assigning text to local variables.
 
playerId = Convert.ToInt32(textPlayerId );
 plyerOrder = Convert.ToInt16(textPlyerOrder.Text);
 BatsmanStatus = textBatsmanStatus.Text;

Comment: You are missing (.Text) in  playerId = Convert.ToInt32(textPlayerId);

Comment: well this is a string (textPlayerId). The main problem is all textboxes are empty.

Comment: textPlayerId  is a string. so do not apply .text for this. string textPlayerId = GVRow.Cells[0].Text;

Comment: @Deepak.Aggrawal : I've done exactly same.

Comment: Try this for find the textbox in grid row (TextBox)GVRow.FindControl("txtPlayingOrder");

Comment: @bhoopendra.sahoo: Did you try the above code?

Comment: I've tried (TextBox)GVRow.FindControl("txtPlayingOrder"); even this one also 
 for (int i = 0; i < gvScheduleBattingScore.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
       
        TextBox tb = (TextBox) gvScheduleBattingScore.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("txtPlayingOrder");
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37167/discussion-between-deepak-aggrawal-and-bhoopendra-sahoo)

Comment: Please show your OnRowDataBound code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Chat discussion with *@bhoopendra.sahoo*, we come to the conclusion that it is a Binding issue.

When Button Click Event is fired, the `GridView` binds again causing the issue.

The fix is to bind the `GridView` only once and restrict its binding during other events.

Answer (score 0):

Add a null checking before converting the textbox value to int

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textPlayerId.Text))
    playerId = Convert.ToInt32(textPlayerId);
```

Also make these changes to you code, to find the textbox controls in the correct cell

```
TextBox textPlyerOrder = (TextBox)GVRow.Cells[2].FindControl("txtPlayingOrder"); 
TextBox textBatsmanStatus = (TextBox)GVRow.Cells[3].FindControl("txtStatus");
```

Comment: My problem is I am getting textPlyerOrder.Text And textBatsmanStatus.Text both are empty.

Comment: Still having the same problem. both textboxes are empty.